# How to set background color kendo angualr2 tabstrip Title

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using [**Kendo-Tabstrip**](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/index) in my Angular 2 app, which works fine.

I now wish to set a background color for the tab-headers only, not the tab content (body) as well.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using CSS:

```
.k-tabstrip-items {
    background: red;
}

.k-tabstrip-items .k-item {
    background: green;
}
```

`k-tabstrip-items` is the strip itself and `k-item` are the different tabs.